# Class throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android

Why does the following method throws an NPE,

```
public ActivityOne extends Activity{
   DataManager dtMan = new DataManager(this)

   public onCreate (){ 
    ...some source code here...
    dtMan.check();
   }
}

public class DataManager(){
   private Context myContext;

   public DataManager (Context context){
     myContext = context;
   }

   Helper helper = new Helper(this);

   public boolean check(){
     helper.open();
     ...some source code here...
   }
}
```

When I view the logcat; I get a java.null.pointer exception, so I did something like

```
public class DataManager(){
   private Context myContext;

   public DataManager (Context context){
     myContext = context;
   }

   public boolean check(Context context){
     **Helper helper = new Helper(context);**
     helper.open();
     ...some source code here...
   }
}
```

And it worked, so what is the difference between the two DataManager in Java/Android programming perspective, thus this approach if I understand correctly must be replicated to as follow:

```
public class DataManager(){
   private Context myContext;

   public DataManager (Context context){
     myContext = context;
   }

   public boolean check(Context context){
     **Helper helper = new Helper(context);**
     helper.open();
     ...some source code here...
   }

   public boolean check2(Context context){
     **Helper helper = new Helper(context);**
     helper.open();
     ...some source code here...
   }

   public boolean check3(Context context){
     **Helper helper = new Helper(context);**
     helper.open();
     ...some source code here...
   }
}
```

Meaning I just can't declare the Helper Class once and use it anywhere the calling class, did I forgot some fundamentals? Please clarify.

Will the context also lead to memory leaks?, if so, how will I fix it?

@EDIT:

Well I forgot to include the Helper Class

public class Helper{
     private Context myContext;

```
 public Helper(Context context){
    myContext = context;
 }

 public void open(){
  //do stuff here
 }
```

}

Comment: interesting `new Helper(this);` where `this` is instance of `DataManager` and it seems like Helper takes a context as paramater ... this should even not compile ...

Comment: The Context `this` is not initialized! init your Datamanager in onCreate and everything will be ok

Comment: @A.S. actually enogh will be move helper initialization into `DataManager ` constructor ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because the DataManager is initialized at field scope in the Activity.

Classes which need a Context should always be initialized in one of the Activity's life cycle methods:

onCreate, onStart, onDestroy, etc.

Like this:

```
private DataManager dataManager;

public void on create(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dataManager = new DataManager(this):
}
```

You also should initialize the Helper class in the DataManager constructor:

```
public class DataManager(){
    private Context context;
    private Helper helper;

    public DataManager (Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.helper = new Helper(this.context);
     }

    public boolean check(Context context){
        helper.open();
        //...some source code here...
    }
}
```

To prevent memory leaks you just need to make sure the DataManager class is not a static instance with an Activity Context.

If you don't need an Activity Context but you're also fine with an Application Context you should use it:

```
public DataManager(Context context){
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    //...
}
```

Comment: that I never knew, I always practiced to initialized everything outside a method, having thought it would have a public visibility, this is what I thought to believe for sometime.

Comment: "this.helper = new Helper(this.context);" - this is the solution wasn't it?

Comment: You should try it out ;)

Comment: ``), i tried to recreate your SO name, hehe, yes, I was just jumping out of joy and wasn't really asking if it was the solution, but I do have a gut feeling it is, I'll try it out quickly.

Comment: one last thing, somewhat related to the question, so what do you call this fundamentals/topics (so I can read further), why Helper helper = new Helper(this) is not working, does this have something to do with scope/s?

Answer (score 0):

Try put

> dtMan = new DataManager(this)

in onCreate method in Activity?

Comment: this will not help, as the problem is not here ... you can pass Activity reference but you can't use it until onCreate ...

Comment: @Selvin, you can pass Activity reference but you can't use it until onCreate, can you please elaborate a little more, just a little bit more... pls.